# Stripe: How to migrate from Charge API to PaymentIntent API in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have used stripe in my one of the projects. I am taking card details from the user and the following code is for payment.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('KEY');

$token = \Stripe\Token::create([
        "card" => [
        "number"    => $paymentModel['number'],
        "exp_month" => $paymentModel['expire_month'],
        "exp_year"  => $paymentModel['expire_year'],
        "cvc"       => $paymentModel['card_cvc'],
        "name"      => $userName
      ]]);

 $customer   = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'email'  => $email,
    'source' => $token['id'],
    ]);

$charge   = \Stripe\Charge::create([
   'amount'      => $chargeableAmount,
   'currency'    => 'usd',
   'description' => "Purchase User",
   'customer'    => $customerId,
]);
```

I got a notification for "Update your integration now for SCA". So I found that I should use PaymentIntent for card payments. I am really confused about these things. The document is confusing and it says so many things so I cannot understand what change I should do to migrate. There is no proper document which describe steps to migrate from Charge API to Payment Intent API.

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [Stripe's Migration Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#saving-cards-checkout), under "Migrate your integration that saves cards on Customer objects" and the "Saving cards after a payment" tab. The text there also includes notes on how to handle Authentication under SCA with `handleCardPayment` on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below article to integrate SCA on your payment solution

[3DS supported Stripe.js Integration with Chargebee APIs](https://www.chargebee.com/tutorials/stripe-js-3ds-token-example.html)

Chargebee has PHP demo application in [github](https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-samples/blob/master/php/php_src/StripeJs3dsCheckout.php) which will help you to understand better.